# sql-server trigger join doesnt work

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, left-join, inner-join

I have been working on this trigger and couldn't figure it out. I have had some help from people here and made a lot of progress but couldn't finish yet.

here is my trigger with join. the insert doesn't happen.... I cannot debug and cannot see the error if there is any. I am using SQL web tool unfortunately

```
CREATE trigger Posts_Raw_To_Queue_Trigger  ON SendNotificationPostsRaw 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SendNotificationPostsQueue (UserID,PostID,SpecialityID)
  SELECT I.PostID, I.UserID, P.CategoryId   
  FROM INSERTED AS I JOIN PostCategoryRelations AS P ON I.PostID= P.PostId
END
```

Comment: Is the PostCategoryRelations record you join to being written in the same transaction, or is it already there?

Comment: You have a different order in `INSERT` and `SELECT` : `INSERT ...(UserId, PostId,...) SELECT I.PostID,I.UserID` . Is it a typo? If not, it may fail due to referential integrity violation

Comment: you are right but that doesnt fix it though

Comment: @Andy Nichols ,PostCategoryRelations record should be written before this trigger

Comment: Is there an explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION started before the trigger executes? You could see this if you PRINTed the value of @@TRANCOUNT from the trigger. Maybe you have a transaction that was not committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Posts_Raw_To_Queue_Trigger

    ON dbo.SendNotificationPostsRaw

    -- please write this if SendNotificationPostsRaw is table 
    AFTER INSERT
    -- or write this if SendNotificationPostsRaw is view
    INSTEAD OF INSERT

    --FOR INSERT

AS BEGIN

    -- check if thete are any rows
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM INSERTED i
    ) RAISERROR('Nothing to insert', 16, 1)


    INSERT INTO dbo.SendNotificationPostsQueue 
    (
          UserID
        , PostID
        , SpecialityID
    )
    SELECT  
          I.PostID
        , I.UserID
        , P.CategoryID
    FROM INSERTED AS I
    JOIN PostCategoryRelations P ON I.PostID = P.PostId

END
```